# How to refresh only one Html.ListBox in asp.net razor?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

I tried to refresh only one Html.ListBox. But i don't know how to do this with ASP. Right now it will refresh the whole page.

Here is my source:
Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KenmerkSelectie(string Kenmerken1, string Buttontype, List<string> VarFromKenmerk1)
{
    if (Buttontype == "submit")
    {
        //Write to a database and process stuff
        return this.RedirectToAction("submitForm");
    }else{
        ViewBag.VarFromKenmerk1 = ...;
        //TODO: Must refresh the ListBox: VarFromKenmerk1;
        //AND AND NOT refresh whole page;
        return View("index");
    }
```

html view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("KenmerkSelectie", "KenmerkSelectie", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "kenmerk1" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Kenmerken1",
    (SelectList)ViewBag.Kenmerk,
    "-- Selecteer een kenmerk--", new
    {
        onchange = "refreshVarFromKenmerk1();"
    })

     @Html.ListBox("VarFromKenmerk1", (SelectList)ViewBag.var, new { @style = "width: 252px; height: 300px" })

    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnNext" name="ButtonType" />
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshVarFromKenmerk1() {
        document.getElementById('kenmerk1').submit();
    }
 </script>
```

Is it possible to achieve this without Javascript? Or better how do I achieve this?

Comment: You want to send a separate `GET` request to populate the select list. Don't try to do both the form `POST` and the select list population in the same controller action. (@beautifulcoder is alluding to this in his answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` in your controller. You can fire an Ajax request like:

```
$('#kenmerk1').change(function () { $.get(); /* this won't work but shows the basics */ });
```

Then, you can return a `JsonResult` in the controller and refresh the list box.